# Crystal reports formula issue

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

In the database table the values 32 or 33 means add or change, I am not getting this to work, the result of this is FALSE> I need to display add/change.

This col is defined as alpha 3.

```
StringVar amnt; 

IF {ACAUDIT.IATRNC} = '032' then amnt = 'ADD'

else

If {ACAUDIT.IATRNC} = '033' then amnt = 'CHANGE'
```

Comment: Do you get an error from the formula editor, or does it validate and just return no value?  Also, the column you're evaluating there, is it a character column, or a number?  Is your formula syntax Crystal or Visual Basic?  Do you suppose you could put up your table schema in your question as well?

Comment: whats the datatype of column where 032 and 033 are stored?

Comment: its alpha column len of 3. this formula returns 'FALSE' on every row. formula is syntax crystal.